# CheckBox at the right of a TextView

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a multi-line TextView and next to it I want to show a checkbox. The problem is that if the text stretches across more than 1 row, the checkbox isn't displayed.

So far, I have (without the ids):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text=""
            android:clickable="false" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how the layout is rendered (notice the missing checkbox):

[image: Missing the checkbox]

If I shorten the text, it's rendered correctly:

[image: Checkbox is there]

Is it possible to add a CheckBox at the right of a multi-line TextView?

Edit: Sorry everyone, I solved the problem pretty soon after asking this question (by adding layout_weight=1), but posted in a wrong thread. I have accepted the answer suggesting that.

Comment: You can try [CheckedTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html) Example here http://www.rochdev.com/2011/08/checkedtextview.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this `android:layout_weight="1"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text=""
            android:clickable="false"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a relative layout inside your linear layout instead of a linear layout inside a linear layout and use [relative layout parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the `CheckBox` a `Weight` value greater than the `TextView` (set its `width` to `0dip` and give it higher `Weight`)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using weights.. try following code

Please try to change weights according to your requirement

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text=""
        android:clickable="false" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use the following in a LinearLayout

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="textfield 1-1"></TextView>
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/CheckBox01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
```

Copied from http://huuah.com/using-tablelayout-on-android/